# Where do I purchase this Trypsin?

Tags: biochemistry, enzymes, units

I am currently on the lookout for Trypsin, but I have some trouble finding something that is fairly cheap, ships to Europe and is equivalent to this Trypsin:

- http://www.emsdiasum.com/microscopy/products/chemicals/tannic.aspx#22200
- Trypsin powder 1:100 from Porcine Pancreas, 25g
- Activity >100 NF units/mg
- Used for whole cell preparation

I've found Trypsin on Sigma:

- http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/sigma/t4799
- Trypsin powder from Porcine Pancreas
- Activity 1,000-2,000 BAEE units/mg
- Suitable for cell culture

However I am not sure how to compare the activity between the two types and ultimately which concentration I should then use in my experiment if I go with the Sigma one (the protocol I am following uses the EMS Trypsin in a 1g:100ml fashion). 
Can anyone shed some light on this? Or perhaps show me the way to some affordable Trypsin that can be shipped to Scandinavia?

Cheers!
/Patricia

*The trypsin will be used for diaphonization (see comment)

Comment: Could you update your question to explicitly state what you will use the trypsin for. Trypsin has a number of uses and the use alters which trypsin is appropriate.

Comment: Hi Michael. Sure! I will use the trypsin for diaphonization (aka. clearing and staining), which is basically a way of dyeing a whole specimen. Trypsins role is to digest the specimen enough so it becomes transparent, but not so much that it falls apart... If that makes no sense there is a nice video about it here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=haopSRCuPdo... I have experience with use of Trypsin with cells - but diaphonization is completely new to me, and the protocols I have give no clue to what type of trypsin they are using.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Sigma-Aldrich](http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/technical-documents/articles/biology/trypsin.html),

> 1 USP Unit = 3.0 BAEE Units
>   1 NF Unit = 1.1 USP Units

So 1 NF unit is roughly equal to 3.3 BAEE units. You can then directly compare the two trypsin powders, since they are preparations of the same enzyme.

Comment: Yeah, I did see that, but the thing that bothered me is then that I need to compare unspecific units like >100 NF and 1,000-2,000 BAEE, and so I am left with questions like "How much is >100 NF? 101 NF? 500 NF?" and "Do I calculate with 1.000 or 2.000 BAEE?"

Comment: But I guess the best solution is to note that 100 NF ~ 330 BAEE and so if I end up buying the Sigma one, I can start out with trying a 1:300 solution and see how that goes :)